# Conda environment with custom python configuration settings

Tags: python, configuration, virtualenv, conda

When installing python from source we get the luxury of configuring with options before installing, e.g.

```
./configure --enabled-shared # other options go here
make altinstall # etc
```

where other options are found at https://docs.python.org/3/using/configure.html

When creating a conda environment, however, we just do

```
conda create -n myenv python
```

Where do we add configuration settings when building python from conda?

Comment: python is not built from source when you install it via conda

Comment: @FlyingTeller Thanks. Then I will not be using conda.

Comment: @FlyingTeller might as well make that an answer - even if trivial it's the fact: "not possible"